# raphaeljs pie dynamic value array change

Tags: jquery, raphael, pie-chart

I use Raphael js pie chart plugin

http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html

i need to refresh the chart values array in every 5 second(need to redraw the pie) - my problem is the following code creates also new pie chart, not just update the exisiting with new values - short: i can't get to pass only the "value" array.

```
 var labels = [],
     values = [60,0],
     i=60,
     j=0
 window.setInterval(function(){
        i--;
        j=j+1;
        if(j>60){
            i=60;
            j=0
        }

        values = [i,j];

       Raphael("holder", 700, 700).pieChart(350, 350, 250, values, labels, "#fff");

 }, 5000);
```

I need just to update with new values the pie not to create new one also.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sensible approach would be to initialise the canvas only once. When you want to redraw the pie chart, clear the canvas (see Paper.clear() in the docs) and call pieChart again, on the same canvas element.

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/5DRUh/

```
(function () {

    var labels = ['value1', 'value2'],
        values = [60, 0],
        i = 60,
        j = 0;

    // Setup the canvas just once
    paper = Raphael('holder', 700, 700);

    window.setInterval(draw, 5000);

    // Draw the piechart when the page loads
    draw();

    function draw(){
        i--;
        j = j + 1;
        if (j > 60) {
            i = 60;
            j = 0;
        }

        values = [i, j];
        paper.clear();
        paper.pieChart(350, 350, 200, values, labels, '#fff');

    }
}());
```

Comment: That's the beauty of linking external files ... I've updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Actually paper.clear() might not be enough, as it didn't work for me.

The piechart() function takes an array of values as input, but after this call returns, your array is no longer the same.

What I did was pass a clone of my array to the piechart() method, this way my data is not clobbered by piechart() function.

Comment: thank you so much, I spent hours on that problem without understanding why this crap would not redraw...